# How to use a entity of one activity(lke button,textview etc) in other activity so that we can apply some logic

Tags: android, android-activity

I actually want to create a button in one activity ,and want to use this button in other activity,and on basic of click on this button,I want to apply some logic in other activity.Is there any way to do it???

Comment: `This is not good practice`, put logic in same Activity which is currently Visible to user and pass data between Activities using `StartActivityForResult` or `StartActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the state of the button to a value and pass it to the next Activity so you can use it.

Look up Intents, Context, and Bundles. These three subjects will tell you what you need to know